# How to switch between gaze and laser?

Tags: aframe, google-cardboard, oculus

My VR experiment's interaction is based on clicking on objects. I'd like it to work on the desktop (with the mouse), on a Cardboard (with a gaze cursor), or with a 3 or 6dof controller (like for example the Oculus Go).

How do I get it to switch based on what's available?

Here's what I have now:

```
<a-scene  antialias="true" cursor="rayOrigin:mouse">
  <a-entity laser-controls="hand: right"></a-entity>
...</a-scene>
```

This works for desktop and OGO, but not on Cardboard. I believe I can add an `<a-cursor>` for a gaze cursor, but then it's there all the time - I only want it to show up when the user is in Cardboard.

Is this possible? How would I go about doing this? Do I perhaps need to write some javascript to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

If you can have a `<a-camera>` entity, you can create a custom component, which will add a fuse cursor only on mobile devices.

You could even have a setup like this:

```
<a-camera>
  <a-entity cursor-check></a-entity>
</a-camera>
```

and add the `cursor` to the empty entity whenever its needed.

---

Check whether you're on a mobile device :

```
AFRAME.registerComponent("cursor-check", {
....
    if(!AFRAME.utils.device.isMobile()) return;
```

and add the cursor component when necessary

```
    this.el.setAttribute("cursor", {
       "fuse": "true",
       "fuse-timeout": "500"
    })
...
```

Check it out [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gftruj/3egn681p/).

---

As Nick has noted, there also are two **[utils](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/docs/core/utils.md#aframeutilsdevice)** which can help distinguish whether you're on a oculus go, or gear vr:

```
AFRAME.utils.device.isOculusGo ()
AFRAME.utils.device.isGearVr ()
```

maybe even `checkHeadsetConnected ()` could be of help

Comment: Interesting. But how do I distinguish whether the mobile device has a 3dof controller? For example on the Oculus Go I want to use the laser, but on a Cardboard I want to use gaze/fuse. Both are running Android and I'm pretty sure that both will show up as "mobile".

Comment: Specifically, I need 3 cases: desktop (show no cursor, use the mouse), 3dof (show laser), and poor man's VR (show gaze cursor).

Comment: I tried it, and on the Go it doesn't show the laser. You can see my attempt at https://glitch.com/edit/#!/therapeutic-hammer?path=index.html:102:11

Comment: Hi fishingpole, you’re right, in my experience isMobile will return true on a go, if you look at the docs for these checks https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/docs/core/utils.md there are checks for isGearVR and isOculusGo, the latter is only available on the master branch so if you don’t want to use that, isGearVR will return true on both gear and go (same browser I think), so perhaps you could check if device isMobile & isGearVR then you might be able to distinguish between mobile and 3dof on those devices. I haven’t tested that though. I’d be interested to hear how you get on.

Comment: I haven't been able to test this. On my Apple device it just says "please place phone in Cardboard holder". Hopefully this'll work once I locate my Cardboard.

Comment: I got my Cardboard, but for some reason it just doesn't work. Isn't AFrame supposed to support Cardboard on iPhones? It just sits there saying "please put your phone in the holder"